# How to get weekday in Swift regardless of the locale settings?

Tags: ios, swift, weekday

In my iOS app user can choose on which day to have certain action active and I am saving each selection as a raw value of `OptionSet`. This all works great.

But I need a way to map current day to the selected options. How can I get some kind of constants for weekdays that do not changed based on whether week starts on Sunday or Monday based on selected locale?

This:

```swift
let weekDay = Calendar.current.component(.weekday, from: Date())
```

Seems like a solution but the `Int` constant is going to vary right based on a locale? According to very short docs from Apple this should be `1` for Sunday in Gregorian calendar.

Is there any way how I can get weekday from `Date` that will be always same?

I would like to map these constants to my `OptionSet` flags and based on that decide whether action should be active in a given day.

Thanks.

Comment: Locale won't affect it at all. You will have more problems with time zone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing up `weekday` and `firstWeekday`.

The [`weekday`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/calendar/component/weekday) component is independent of the locale, in the Gregorian Calendar 1 is always Sunday, 2 Monday etc.